# Как лучше всего сделать слайд-шоу?

Tags: javascript

Как лучше всего сделать слайд-шоу? Чем плоха эта функция?

```
function slideShow(){
    document.getElementById('back_slide').onclick = previousSlide
    document.getElementById('go_slide').onclick = nextSlide

    var num = 1
    var placeSlideImg = document.getElementById('slide')
    img1 = new Image(); img1.src = "tiger.jpg"
    img2 = new Image(); img2.src = "fish.jpg"
    img3 = new Image(); img3.src = "dog.jpg"  
    img4 = new Image(); img4.src = "cat.jpg"
    img5 = new Image(); img5.src = "mouse.jpg"

function nextSlide(){
    num += 1
    if (num == 6){ 
            num=1
    }
    placeSlideImg.src = eval("img" +num+ ".src")
}

function previousSlide(){
    num -= 1
    if (num == 0){ 
            num = 5
    }
    placeSlideImg.src = eval("img" +num+ ".src")
  }

}
```

Comment: А почему эта функция плохая? Она не работает что-ли? Да! И не забывайте везде где надо ставить точку с запятой. Не смотря даже на то, что компилятор JS сам расставит точки с запятой, иногда он их может поставить не в том месте, и найти такую ошибку будет тяжело.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

смеётесь что ли?

```
eval("img" +num+ ".src")
```

массивы? не, не слышал.

```
imges = [
    new Image(), 
    new Image(), 
    new Image(), 
    new Image(), 
    new Image()
];

// более разумный подход:
var imges = [];
for(var i = 5; i--;)
{
    imges[i] = new Image();
}

imges[0].src = "tiger.jpg";
imges[1].src = "fish.jpg";
...
```

Comment: @Spectre - в реально разумном подходе должен использоваться обработчик загрузки изображений, если делать именно по человечески, то код будет "немного" больших размеров. И даже с использованием jquery, код будет, не столь очевидный.

Comment: да-да, тоже надо было завести массив/хещ имён и тоже в цикле пройтись, но я по крайней мере исправил сей китайский код:

    img4.src = "cat.jpg"
    img5.src = "mouse.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Проще плагин бесплатный прикрутить, поищите галереи для jquery